# Detect #tags from html element and decorate it with color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all #tag from html elements with some decorated color or surrounded by any tags so that I can decorate it.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">hello #there, how #are you?</div>
        <div id="two">i am learning #javascript and #jquery client side technologies </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to decorate **#there**, **#are**, **#javascript** and **#jquery** like changing colors, fonts or anything you can use `<span>There</span>`. Now you can give different styles to those text. Like `<span style="color:blue">There</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qfd8jd/)

```
var txt = document.getElementById('one');
txt.innerHTML = txt.innerHTML.replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, "<span class='hashtag'>#$1</span>");
```

Replace in whole document [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qfd8jd/1/)

```
document.body.innerHTML =  document.body.innerHTML.replace(/#([^ ]+)/g, "<span class='hashtag'>#$1</span>");
```

Comment: thanks saurabh, your solution works fine, but i want to replace whole documents hashtags then is it appropriate to implement same solution?

Comment: there is one problem with your solution, if there is another div inside div one with some #attributes like <div id="one">abc #xyz <div data-target="#one"></div></div>.
For such scenario this solution will not be applicable